# ILMerge Command Error

Tags: c#, dll, ilmerge

Error: Cant find the target platform directory

Following is the error in am getting , I am vs 2010 with .net 4.5 on windows xp. I am using ILMerge first time.

Following Picture has query

http://i50.tinypic.com/2lj2788.png

Kindly please comment if something missing before giving me a -1 point. So i can correct it and learn from the users ;).

Comment: You need double quotes around the `C:\Program Files` path in your command line.

Comment: Thank you. Problem Solved. Also thanks for -1 point.

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the framework path into quotes. I had exactly the same problem, and this was my solution.

Example:
/targetplatform:v4,"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"

Have fun!